# App Crashing in Heroku/ Working in Localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have an app running in heroku as well it's database. Everything seems to be working but the Application crashed. I don't get any errors in my terminal. The only thing I get from heroku is this

```
2021-04-06T02:07:13.448162+00:00 app[web.1]: > violet_vines@2.0.0 start
2021-04-06T02:07:13.448163+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server
2021-04-06T02:07:13.448163+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-06T02:07:14.115150+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-04-06T02:07:14.177976+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
2021-04-06T09:26:43.558948+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=violet-vines.herokuapp.com request_id=00a40ed1-4617-42d9-a984-f65f1e39160a fwd="77.88.5.215" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

In Server index.js:

```
const startListening = () => {
  // start listening (and create a 'server' object representing our server)
  const server = app.listen(PORT, () =>
    console.log(`Mixing it up on port ${PORT}`)
  )

  // set up our socket control center
  const io = socketio(server)
  require('./socket')(io)
}

const syncDb = () => db.sync()

async function bootApp() {
  await sessionStore.sync()
  await syncDb()
  await createApp()
  await startListening()
}
// This evaluates as true when this file is run directly from the command line,
// i.e. when we say 'node server/index.js' (or 'nodemon server/index.js', or 'nodemon server', etc)
// It will evaluate false when this module is required by another module - for example,
// if we wanted to require our app in a test spec
if (require.main === module) {
  bootApp()
} else {
  createApp()
}
```

In Package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build-client": "webpack",
    "build-client-watch": "webpack -w",
    "deploy": "script/deploy",
    "heroku-token": "script/encrypt-heroku-auth-token.js",
    "lint": "eslint ./ --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "lint-fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "prepare": "if [ -d .git ]; then npm-merge-driver install; fi",
    "prettify": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,json,css,scss,md}\"",
    "postinstall": "touch secrets.js",
    "seed": "node script/seed.js",
    "start": "node server",
    "start-dev": "NODE_ENV='production' npm run build-client-watch & NODE_ENV='production' npm run start-server",
    "start-server": "nodemon server -e html,js,scss --ignore public --ignore client",
    "test": "NODE_ENV='test' mocha \"./server/**/*.spec.js\" \"./client/**/*.spec.js\" \"./script/**/*.spec.js\" --require @babel/polyfill --require @babel/register"
  }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please post your code as code and not screenshots.

Comment: Sorry, I made the changes